# VBA recursive function that stores data in a dictionary

Tags: vba, dictionary, recursion

I have a function which recursively, it receives three parameters (a folder path, recursive search switch and list of file types as variant/array), the output is a dictionary of paths of all files in searched folder (example folder in picture)
[image]

The idea is to use a shell “Application object” then, test all items (files or folders) that belong to that “folder item object” and if they meet a certain file type they get added to a dictionary
If the object being tested is a folder then, it gets passed for processing. in this code I used “GoTo” keyword to do the folder processing without calling the Function from within itself, because I tried calling the function from within itself and a new dictionary was created every time the function was called and the old dictionary values are replaced.

**Question is:**

How do I call the function recursively avoiding the issue of creating a new dictionary without using GoTo keyword and without defining another dictionary outside the function?

Also, any ideas to improve the current code would be welcomed.

**Here is the code**

```
Sub test()

    Dim fpath As String
    fpath = "C:\TestFolder"

    Dim arrFileTypes() As Variant
    arrFileTypes = Array(".docx", ".doc", ".rtf", ".txt")

    'let's test if the function works
    Call ListItemsInFolder2(fpath, True, arrFileTypes)

End Sub


Function ListItemsInFolder2(FolderPath As String, LookInSubFolders As Boolean, ByRef SearchedFileTypes As Variant)
        Dim PathsDict As Object
        Set PathsDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        Dim ShellAppObject As Object
        Dim objFolder As Object
        Dim fldItem As Object
        Dim i As Long
        Dim k As Long
        k = 0

    ShellNewObj:
        'check if there is already shell objs from previous searches and set them to nothing
        If (Not ShellAppObject Is Nothing) Then
            Set ShellAppObject = Nothing
            FolderPath = fldItem.Path
        End If

        If (Not objFolder Is Nothing) Then
            Set objFolder = Nothing
        End If

        Set ShellAppObject = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        Set objFolder = ShellAppObject.Namespace("" & FolderPath)
        'k = 0

        For Each fldItem In objFolder.Items

            If InStr(1, fldItem.Parent, ".zip", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then    'vbTextCompare ==> negelct case sensitivity of file extension
                'its not a zip file
                If (fldItem.IsFolder) Then    'check if the current item is a folder
                    'the item is a folder
                Else    'the item is a file

                    For i = LBound(SearchedFileTypes) To UBound(SearchedFileTypes)
                        'check if the file extension ex(.doc) matches the input from array
                        If Mid(fldItem.Name, InStrRev(fldItem.Name, ".", , vbTextCompare)) = LCase(SearchedFileTypes(i)) Then
                            PathsDict.Add Key:=k, Item:=fldItem.Path    'add those files to the dictionary
                            k = k + 1
                        End If
                    Next i

                End If
                If (fldItem.IsFolder And LookInSubFolders) Then
                    GoTo ShellNewObj:

                    '*** here is the old line of code ***
                    'ListItemsInFolder fldItem.Path, LookInSubFolders, SearchedFileTypes
                    '***

                End If
            Else  'its a zip file
                'do nothing and bypass it
            End If
        Next fldItem

        ListItemsInFolder2 = PathsDict.Items
        Set ShellAppObject = Nothing
        Set PathsDict = Nothing
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all the files matching one or more extensions with Scripting.FileSystemObject:

```
Sub UsageExample()
  Dim files()
  files = FindFiles("C:\temp", True, "*.docx", "*.txt")

  Debug.Print Join(files, vbCrLf)
End Sub

''
' Function to search all the files matching on or more pattern
' @folder {String} Initial folder
' @subfolders {Boolean} If true the function will search in the sub folders
' @patterns {Array} List of patterns to search. Ex: "*.txt"
' Returns an array of full paths
''
Public Function FindFiles(folder As String, subfolders As Boolean, ParamArray patterns())
  Dim results$(), count&, fso As Object
  ReDim results(0 To 255)
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  FindFilesRecursive results, count, fso.GetFolder(folder), Array(patterns)(0), subfolders

  ' resize and return the results
  If count Then
    ReDim Preserve results(0 To count - 1)
    FindFiles = results
  End If
End Function

Private Sub FindFilesRecursive(results$(), count&, folder As Object, patterns, recursive As Boolean)
  Dim item As Object, name$

  ' handle each file
  For Each item In folder.files
    name = item.name
    For Each pattern In patterns
      If name Like pattern Then
        If count > UBound(results) Then ReDim Preserve results(0 To UBound(results) * 2)
        results(count) = item.path
        count = count + 1
      End If
    Next
  Next

  ' handle each folder
  If recursive Then
    For Each item In folder.subfolders
      FindFilesRecursive results, count, item, patterns, recursive
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```

To get all the files matching one or more extensions with Dir:

```
''
' Function to search all the files matching on or more pattern
' @folder {String} Initial folder
' @subfolders {Boolean} If true the function will search in the sub folders
' @patterns {Array} List of patterns to search. Ex: "*.txt"
' Returns an array of full paths
''
Function FindFiles(ByVal folder$, subfolders As Boolean, ParamArray patterns())
  Dim fname$, dname$, i&, pattern, files$(), filesLen&, folders$(), foldersLen&

  If Right(folder, 1) <> "\" Then folder = folder & "\"
  ReDim files$(0 To 1024)
  ReDim folders$(0 To 1024)
  folders(0) = folder
  foldersLen = 1

  Do While i < foldersLen
    folder = folders(i)

    ' handle files
    fname = Dir(folder)
    Do While Len(fname)
        For Each pattern In patterns
          If fname Like pattern Then
            If filesLen > UBound(files) Then ReDim Preserve files(0 To UBound(files) * 2)
            files(filesLen) = folder & fname
            filesLen = filesLen + 1
          End If
        Next
        fname = Dir()
    Loop

    ' handle sub folders
    If subfolders Then
      dname = Dir(folder, vbDirectory)
      Do While Len(dname)
        If Asc(dname) <> 46 Then ' if doesn't start with "."
          If (GetAttr(folder & dname) And vbDirectory) <> 0 Then
            If foldersLen > UBound(folders) Then
              ReDim Preserve folders(0 To UBound(folders) * 2)
            End If
            folders(foldersLen) = folder & dname & "\"
            foldersLen = foldersLen + 1
          End If
        End If
        dname = Dir()
      Loop
    End If

    i = i + 1
  Loop

  ' resize and return the results
  If filesLen Then
    ReDim Preserve files(0 To filesLen - 1)
    FindFiles = files
  End If
End Function
```

Execution times on a folder containing more than 30000 files:

```
FindFiles with FileSystemObject : 23078 ms
FindFiles with Dir()            :  5000 ms
```

Comment: thanks for the help, why didn't you merge the two functions together?. another thing, FSO and ArrayList Obj are less efficient in terms of performance than Shell obj and dictionaries. it would be nice if you can write the code using shell object. i tried your code and it works fine on a folder with 1142 files but it takes 2.7 seconds which is a long time for my project. I also noted that my code above doesn't add all the files in the folder, can you **Or Anyone** check whats wrong?

Comment: Thank you very much, so with Dir() it's 5 seconds..and where did u get the  30,000 files? :) .

Comment: you didn't take into consideration the Unicode letters and numbers that may be found in `dname ` as you check if its a directory or not. I ran into this issue checking a list of Arabic file names that have hindi origin numbers in them where the number "٢" in Hindi got compared to its Arabic equivalent "2" and an error was raised cuz no such file is found. I'll try to solve that problem, feel free to help